# How to stop a javascript function stop when user taps the screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `scrollTop()` button which, onclick, performs scroll to top action. I want to stop that action when a user touch the screen. See, When user wants to read a specific paragraph or view a video, he wants to stop the scroll top action but `scrollTop()` goes to top of the page and user can't stop it in middle. I used `stopPropogation` but it didn't work. Is there any function which can stop scroll action when user touch the screen. I think this details are enough for making a proper function.

I use the following code for scrollTop action. https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/WNxGopP

Comment: Please include code in the question, not only on an external site like CodePen. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so.

Comment: Add a variable to determine when it should stop making `setTimeout`s https://jsfiddle.net/6p0xq8eg/ (codepen needs login, so copied to a fiddle) (or use .animate and .stop)

Comment: @freedomn-m, Thankyou. Could you please mark it as the answer to this question.